# how to process Qt events one by one?

Tags: qt, timer, delay

I wrote a Qt application that works with qt events such as QTimer,QTcpSocket and etc,. The problem is occurred when the program has a delay. I want to know which events cause this delay!

To do this, I want to process all events one by one and also obtain corresponding objects for process these events and finally, I want to get type of the event!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? How exactly are you trying to use them?

Answer (score 0):

QTimer, QTcpSocket, etc. are not exactly **events**, these classes do their processings in a different thread than the main thread. If you need any more explanation let me know.

In order to not letting them run simultaneously this is something you can start with:

```
QThread *Thread = new QThread();

QTimer * T = new QTimer();
T->setInterval(1000);
T->moveToThread(Thread);
T->start();
// After some checkings
QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket();
socket->moveToThread(Thread);
// And so on ...
```